# Compare two dataframes and find rows based on a value with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames. column "video_path" is common in both the dataframes. I need to extract details from df1 if it matches with df2 and also with the value of yes/no.

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

What i tried

```
newdf= df1.merge(frame, left_on='video_path', right_on='Video_path', how='inner')
```

But I'm sure its not correct.

code to create data frames

```
df1 = {'video_path': {0: 'video/file_path/1.mp4',  1: 'video/file_path/1.mp4',  2: 'video/file_path/1.mp4',  3: 'video/file_path/2.mp4',  4: 'video/file_path/2.mp4',  5: 'video/file_path/2.mp4',  6: 'video/file_path/2.mp4',  7: 'video/file_path/2.mp4',  8: 'video/file_path/3.mp4',  9: 'video/file_path/3.mp4',  10: 'video/file_path/3.mp4',  11: 'video/file_path/4.mp4',  12: 'video/file_path/4.mp4',  13: 'video/file_path/4.mp4',  14: 'video/file_path/4.mp4',  15: 'video/file_path/5.mp4',  16: 'video/file_path/5.mp4',  17: 'video/file_path/5.mp4',  18: 'video/file_path/5.mp4',  19: 'video/file_path/6.mp4',  20: 'video/file_path/6.mp4',  21: 'video/file_path/6.mp4',  22: 'video/file_path/6.mp4',  23: 'video/file_path/6.mp4'}, 'frame_details': {0: 'frame_1.jpg',  1: 'frame_2.jpg',  2: 'frame_3.jpg',  3: 'frame_1.jpg',  4: 'frame_2.jpg',  5: 'frame_3.jpg',  6: 'frame_4.jpg',  7: 'frame_5.jpg',  8: 'frame_1.jpg',  9: 'frame_2.jpg',  10: 'frame_3.jpg',  11: 'frame_1.jpg',  12: 'frame_2.jpg',  13: 'frame_3.jpg',  14: 'frame_4.jpg',  15: 'frame_1.jpg',  16: 'frame_2.jpg',  17: 'frame_3.jpg',  18: 'frame_4.jpg',  19: 'frame_1.jpg',  20: 'frame_2.jpg',  21: 'frame_3.jpg',  22: 'frame_4.jpg',  23: 'frame_5.jpg'}, 'width': {0: 520,  1: 520,  2: 520,  3: 120,  4: 120,  5: 120,  6: 120,  7: 120,  8: 720,  9: 720,  10: 720,  11: 1080,  12: 1080,  13: 1080,  14: 1080,  15: 480,  16: 480,  17: 480,  18: 480,  19: 640,  20: 640,  21: 640,  22: 640,  23: 640}, 'height': {0: 225,  1: 225,  2: 225,  3: 120,  4: 120,  5: 120,  6: 120,  7: 120,  8: 480,  9: 480,  10: 480,  11: 1920,  12: 1920,  13: 1920,  14: 1920,  15: 640,  16: 640,  17: 640,  18: 640,  19: 480,  20: 480,  21: 480,  22: 480,  23: 480}, 'hasAudio': {0: 'yes',  1: 'yes',  2: 'yes',  3: 'yes',  4: 'yes',  5: 'yes',  6: 'yes',  7: 'yes',  8: 'yes',  9: 'yes',  10: 'yes',  11: 'no',  12: 'no',  13: 'no',  14: 'no',  15: 'no',  16: 'no',  17: 'no',  18: 'no',  19: 'yes',  20: 'yes',  21: 'yes',  22: 'yes',  23: 'yes'}}
```

```
df2 = {'Video_path': {0: 'video/file_path/1.mp4',
  1: 'video/file_path/2.mp4',
  2: 'video/file_path/4.mp4',
  3: 'video/file_path/6.mp4',
  4: 'video/file_path/7.mp4',
  5: 'video/file_path/8.mp4',
  6: 'video/file_path/9.mp4'},
 'isPresent': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap `df1` and `df2` with left join and `indicator` parameter, last set column `isPresent` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
newdf= df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'video_path':'Video_path'}), 
                 on='Video_path', 
                 how='left', 
                 indicator=True)

newdf['isPresent'] = newdf.pop('_merge').map({'both':'yes', 'left_only':'no'})
print (newdf)
               Video_path isPresent frame_details   width  height hasAudio
0   video/file_path/1.mp4       yes   frame_1.jpg   520.0   225.0      yes
1   video/file_path/1.mp4       yes   frame_2.jpg   520.0   225.0      yes
2   video/file_path/1.mp4       yes   frame_3.jpg   520.0   225.0      yes
3   video/file_path/2.mp4       yes   frame_1.jpg   120.0   120.0      yes
4   video/file_path/2.mp4       yes   frame_2.jpg   120.0   120.0      yes
5   video/file_path/2.mp4       yes   frame_3.jpg   120.0   120.0      yes
6   video/file_path/2.mp4       yes   frame_4.jpg   120.0   120.0      yes
7   video/file_path/2.mp4       yes   frame_5.jpg   120.0   120.0      yes
8   video/file_path/4.mp4       yes   frame_1.jpg  1080.0  1920.0       no
9   video/file_path/4.mp4       yes   frame_2.jpg  1080.0  1920.0       no
10  video/file_path/4.mp4       yes   frame_3.jpg  1080.0  1920.0       no
11  video/file_path/4.mp4       yes   frame_4.jpg  1080.0  1920.0       no
12  video/file_path/6.mp4       yes   frame_1.jpg   640.0   480.0      yes
13  video/file_path/6.mp4       yes   frame_2.jpg   640.0   480.0      yes
14  video/file_path/6.mp4       yes   frame_3.jpg   640.0   480.0      yes
15  video/file_path/6.mp4       yes   frame_4.jpg   640.0   480.0      yes
16  video/file_path/6.mp4       yes   frame_5.jpg   640.0   480.0      yes
17  video/file_path/7.mp4        no           NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
18  video/file_path/8.mp4        no           NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
19  video/file_path/9.mp4        no           NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN
```